# Error while creating mahout model

Tags: mahout

I am training mahout classifier for my data,
Following commands i issued to create mahout model

```
./bin/mahout seqdirectory -i /tmp/mahout-work-root/MyData-all -o /tmp/mahout-work-root/MyData-seq

./bin/mahout seq2sparse -i /tmp/mahout-work-root/MyData-seq -o /tmp/mahout-work-root/MyData-vectors -lnorm -nv -wt tfidf

./bin/mahout split -i /tmp/mahout-work-root/MyData-vectors/tfidf-vectors --trainingOutput /tmp/mahout-work-root/MyData-train-vectors --testOutput /tmp/mahout-work-root/MyData-test-vectors --randomSelectionPct 40 --overwrite --sequenceFiles -xm sequential

./bin/mahout trainnb -i /tmp/mahout-work-root/Mydata-train-vectors -el -o /tmp/mahout-work-root/model -li /tmp/mahout-work-root/labelindex -ow
```

When i try to create the model using trainnb command i am getting the following Exception :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.BayesUtils.writeLabelIndex(BayesUtils.java:119) at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.training.TrainNaiveBayesJob.createLabelIndex(TrainNaiveBayesJob.java:152)`

What could be the problem here?

Note: Original Example mentioned [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Twenty+Newsgroups) works fine.

Comment: An attempt was made to access an array element with an index that is outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be the problem of how you put your training files.
The files should be organized as following:

MyData-All

\classA

```
 -file1
 -file2
 -...
```

\classB

```
 -filex
```

....